# Can such function exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Can such complex-valued function exist that

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac 1{f(x)}=1$$?

What about

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac 1{Re(f(x))}=1$$?

Answer (score 4):

No, if it did then by the product law of limits $$1 = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{1}{f(x)} = 0\cdot 1 = 0$$
giving us a contradiction. If $L = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exist and $L\not =0 $ then we always have $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{L}$.

Comment: What about the second part of the question?

Comment: @Anixx By the same argument: if $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = 0$ then $\lim_{x\to x_0} \text{Re}(f(x)) = 0$ so $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{1}{\text{Re}(f(x))}$ cannot be equal to $1$ (it must be $\pm\infty$).

Answer (score 1):

Such a function does not exist because of an elementary theorem that states that if $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ both exist, then $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$

Comment: What about the second part?

Comment: No. Because if $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)=0$, then $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)|=|0|=0$, so $\lim_{z \to z_0} \sqrt{Re(f(z))^2+Im(f(z))^2}=0$ and that implies $\lim_{z\to z_0} Re(f(z))=0$ Now apply the elementary theorem i stated in answer.

Comment: Also - When speaking of complex functions as opposed to real valued functions, it is customary to use $z$ as the variable instead of $x$.